# Sdl Sites 9 - Dxa 2.1 Link resolving with tcm id

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa-2.1, link-resolver

I have a DXA 2.1 application that uses elastic search module. The module stores the tcm id of an image and an internal link to a component on another page.

Using this page, [Handling an image in a Multimedia Component](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-7AB5CCD3-89FF-4D95-832A-ACC34C47BA84.xml&docid=GUID-D655EA6D-11F1-41A0-A618-1E974C1B05DC&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-D655EA6D-11F1-41A0-A618-1E974C1B05DC)

I used all three methods described there but my images are not being rendered as expected. given a tcm id, how can I resolve to images and internal component links?

Comment: What is the “Elastic Search Module” you are referring to, exactly?

Comment: The documentation topic you refer to is about old-style (CM-side) templating. DXA uses a Dynamic Delivery architecture, where CM-side templates render raw data (JSON) and the “real templating” (rendering) is done on Delivery side (in your MVC Web Application).

Comment: @RickPannekoek the elastic search module I'm referring to is si4t search module using elastic search. Elastic search stores the tcm id of images and links currently but when I perform a search I need to be able to resolve those links and display the content appropriately.
Is there a way to use the tcm id to be able to display images and link resolve components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [DXA Search Module](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-net/Search)? This Module provides SI4T-based Search functionality to a DXA-based Web Application.  It comes with support for Solr and AWS CloudSearch OOTB, but allows adding other Search Providers.

As a matter of fact, an ElasticSearch integration has also been created: https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/tds-event-presentation-si4t-based-elasticsearch-integration-for-sdl-tridion-web-8-with-dxa-2-0/

Or is that maybe what you are referring to?

Do I understand correctly that your problem lies in embedded images and Component Links in the search results? So, you want to post-process the Search results to resolve Component Links?

In general, the DXA Framework provides a [Link Resolver](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/2.1.0/Sdl.Web.Common/Interfaces/ILinkResolver.cs) for the purpose of resolving Component Links (to either a published page containing the Component or the published binary data of a MM Component).

Comment: Thank you! The link resolver reference you shared solved my issue. I am indeed using the DXA Search module with a custom elastic search extension.